# Is there a way to remove symbol from date in x++?

Tags: date, data-conversion, x++

I am importing fields from Excel to my journal. The problem is - it does not import dates that have a dot or slash in end of the date, like `01.01.2020.` The field is just empty.

I am trying to find a way to remove teh last symbol, if it exists. I tried `str test = date2Str(_country, 123, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);`, but it will take data that does not have a dot or slash in the end. It could be easy to work with date if it was a string, but I am failing to convert it to a string because of that dot or slash in end of the date...

It only converts `01.01.2020` format but it does not convert `01.01.2020.` Any suggestions would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Storing a date in a variable `_country` does not _feel_ right...

Comment: Im inserting data on run() method, but before i insert date from  excel into journal field, i call my convertDate() method where i give parameter date value from excel. it looks like this -  table.field = this.convertDate(range.get_Item(i, 50).Value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Clean up the source data. I cannot image that Excel stores proper date values with a trailing `.` or `/`.

**Option 2**

How are you fetching the Excel values? Does your third party (?) solution offer a method like `myCell.getDateValue()` that returns a `date` type instead of a `string` type?

**Option 3**

You could apply a simple [`substr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions#substr) with length=8 to trim of any trailing characters. The line of code below works for me.

```
date d = str2Date(subStr('01.01.2020.', 1, 8), 123);
```